# Detect text regions in a flowchart using Python and OpenCV3

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I am trying to identify portions of the image that has text. For this, I am using OpenCV (v.3) first to pre-process the image and then add rectangles/boxes to the text portions.

My code below does report some contours. See code, input image and output below.

Code:

```
import os,sys,cv2,pytesseract

## IMAGE
afile           = "test-small.jpg"

def reader(afile):
    aimg            = cv2.imread(afile,0)
    print("Image Shape%s | Size:%s" % (aimg.shape,aimg.size))
    return aimg

def boundbox(aimg):
    out_path2                   = "%s-tagged.jpg" % (afile.rpartition(".")[0])
    ret,thresh                  = cv2.threshold(aimg,127,255,0)
    image, contours, hierarchy  = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    acount = 0
    for contour in contours:
            acount+=1
            x, y, w, h        = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            print("Coordinates",x,y,w,h)
            if w < 100 and h < 100:  ## Avoid tagging small objects i.e. false positives
                continue

            cv2.rectangle(aimg, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 8) ##

    print("Total contours found:%s" % (acount))
    cv2.imwrite(out_path2,aimg)
    return out_path2

def main():
    aimg        = reader(afile)
    bimg        = boundbox(aimg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Test image:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Problem is that (1) rectangles are not visible on image and (2) detection of text portions is inaccurate. How can improve the above code to detect portions with text?

Thanks for helping.

Bade

Comment: what is your problem? what is your question? remove your example and replace it by a minimal one. this is too much information.

Answer (score 1):

Try resizing the image before applying to the threshold. You can also try out erosion and dilation functions before applying contours.